# Android Failed to instantiate one or more classes

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I have a running project and all the xml files are showing me the error message `Android Failed to instantiate one or more classes`. The program still works.

I cleaned the cache and used invalidate Caches and Restart.

Here the Full message:

> The following classes could not be instantiated android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom view to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)
    at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)
    at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:250)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:213)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:146)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Check for the resource file and values in it.

Comment: @AmirKhan What is the selected theme in the preview?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In `styles.xml`,

Changing the theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` has worked for me.

Comment: This message had annoyed me for weeks. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I finally found second styles.xml in values-v21 and updated it. Now it works correctly.

Comment: How the hell did you figure that out?! This solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Problem started for me after upgrading to Android Studio 3.0.1. This fixed it for me, thanks.

Comment: @vinod Thanks it worked for me but I have doubt .I have changed the styles Theme so is there any changes applied to application or working same like how it was worked before adding the Base in styles

Comment: There is no Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. And i am using this only. what to do?

Comment: Or it might be `MaterialComponents.Light`, should be in error message

Answer (score 6):

Finally, after 4 days of facing the same error I resolved this on my own:

Click on

> Build--> Make Build

and then

> Refresh the layout.

Comment: @DikShU you can refresh the layout in the UI preview screen

Answer (score 1):

In the `build.gradle` (Module: `app`) change the implementation of `appcompat` to a previous version by searching the `developer.google`

This is an error in the android framework usually happens in the alpha and beta appcompat versions.

Hope this helps.