# i get error in android studio design view

Tags: android

After I upgraded the dependency to latest version of appcompat-v7:26.0.2 from version 23.0.1, build version from 25.0.0 to 26.0.1,

i tried to clear cache and rebulid as it recommended by Android studio, still throwing the error.

i get error in android studio in design view. can anyone help me with this error to solve.!!!

```
{
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.tutorials.hp.Tiktokads"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile project(':picasso-2.5.2')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.jineshfrancs:LazyLoadingViews:ae99f38b93@aar'
    compile 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
,
```

**I Get Below Erorr**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)
        at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)
        at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:250)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:213)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:146)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
        at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You can try this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304333/android-failed-to-instantiate-one-or-more-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304333/android-failed-to-instantiate-one-or-more-classes)

Comment: without action bar  Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: fixed after adding this tkx<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>