# Failed to instantiate one or more calsses (android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView)

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, toolbar

### Background

I am facing this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:788)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)
    at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:212)
    at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:206)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getFont(TintTypedArray.java:119)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:208)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:152)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:81)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:250)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:213)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:146)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

for every layout (.xml) in the app.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45399080/4669744). above xml Error went away but views are not rendered correctly. Few days ago, my app was working correctly without adding Base. I am using version control so I am sure `Base` was not the issue. 
I was testing Universal Image Loader library. After testing only, I reverted all changes. After that this error popped up on every xml. (Every,thing was working fine till last commit). I don't know what is broken? 
I have tried other solution as well( Invalidate caches and stuff. but all in vain).

**Gradle build (app)**:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
```

Comment: are you using custom fonts in your textview ?

Comment: yup. But It's working fine though.

Comment: Logs are somewhat related to loading fonts failure

Comment: you are right. I am looking into that as well. But Adding `Base` in style fix this. (But views are not rendered correctly) It's very confusing because couple of days ago It was working fine without `Base`

Comment: Did you updated dependencies in gradle ?

Comment: nope. I didn't touch the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried rebuild/clean project ?! sometimes this type of errors are solved by that or invalidate caches and restart ? try it ,might help.

Comment: I tried everything.  Now, I just reinstalled everything from scratch on Win 7 (Before I was using Ubuntu). I guess my previous installation got corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:

Open - "styles.xml"

Change - parent="Base.Theme.AppCompact.(your preferred style)"

Comment: A little explanation should help too.